# UI Bootstrap typeahead promise issues with angular-formly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-formly

I am using angular-formly with integrated ui bootstrap typeahead to query an api via a service. The promises were resolved properly, but typeaheads list only shows the data of the elapsed input query.

Simple example: I type: "Bern", the service fires four requests for:

1. query_term=B
2. query_term=Be
3. query_term=Ber
4. query_term=Bern

The promises were resolved properly and in the right order. But typeahead list suggestions with the data from query_term=Ber and not the last query_term=Bern.

Any suggestions?

Here are code details:

Service:

```
var srv = {        
        getName: function (query_term) {},        
    };

srv.getName = function (query_term) {
return $http.get(srv._baseUrl + '/locating/api/autocomplete?query_term=' + query_term)
        .then(function(res) {
            return res.data;
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
};

return {    
        getName: function (query_term) {
            return srv.getName(query_term);
        }
};
```

(formly) Controller:

```
{
            key: '_name',
            type: 'autocompleteNoWildcard',
            templateOptions: {
                options: [],
                onChange: function ($viewValue, $scope) {                        
                    if (typeof $viewValue != 'undefined') {
                        return $scope.templateOptions.options = locationService.getName($viewValue);                            
                    };
                }
            }
        },
```

Html template:

```
formlyConfig.setType({
            name: 'autocompleteNoWildcard',
            template: '<input type="text" autocomplete="off" ng-model="model._name" uib-typeahead="item.label for item in to.options" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control">',
            wrapper: ['bootstrapLabel', 'bootstrapHasError'],
        });
```

Comment: Are you saying that the `onChange` handler is firing, but the typeahead options are not getting updated?

Comment: They do get an update but with data from the previous query, as I described above.

Comment: So the data getting passed into the `onChange` handler is not correct?  Since that's the data you're setting on `templateOptions.options`.

Comment: Indeed, but if I log the response data from the `locationService.getName($viewValue)` promise to the console, the data seems to be properly passed to `$scope.templateOptions.options`.

Comment: The next thing I would try is to remove formly from the equation temporarily to see if the typeahead component is behaving correctly.  You've got a few levels of stuff here and proper debugging would dictate to try and isolate it to as small of an area as possible.  Do that and let me know what happens.

Comment: What should I say, removing angular-formly from the equation leads to a correctly behaving component. Thanks @icfantv for the comment. I will get a further look at formly integration.

Answer (score 0):

Put a throttle and start polling when the name is longer to 3 characters.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.